# Sign in with Apple: Error: Sign-Up Not Completed

Tags: ios, swift, apple-login

Working with apple id login, configured all required staff.

Enable sign in with Apple in developer account.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AuthenticationServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleIDButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc private func appleIDButtonPressed() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        
    }
}
```

When tap on login button and verify face show UI error, but delegate not called.

[image of UI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVRcj.jpg)

Comment: Paste in the actual code and not an image of the code.  You could state that you are getting the error message "Sign-Up Not Completed" instead of the image.  Not using images can help at getting answers faster.

Comment: @MwcsMac help pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an issue Apple-side, I tried everything yesterday it didn't work and now it's working today. :)

Comment: No problem ! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)